# mixing .selectindex and .selectitem how to detect negative values for loop

Tags: vb.net, count, selecteditem, listboxitem, selectedindex

I have 1 PictureBox, 1 ListBox to select a file (filename), 1 specific path (lastfoldr), it load images correctly and changes to the next and previous images, but im trying to make a loop of the images when the user try to change to the next image when is at last photo.

```
Private Sub ShowPrevImage()
    ListBox5.SelectedIndex = -1
    'If ListBox5.SelectedIndex < 1 Then 'here is the problem
    '    ListBox5.SelectedIndex = ListBox5.Items.Count - 1
    'End If
    Me.PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(lastfoldr & (ListBox5.SelectedItem))
End Sub

Private Sub ShowNextImage()
    ListBox5.SelectedIndex = +1
  '  If ListBox5.SelectedIndex > ListBox5.Items.Count Then 'here is the problem too
   '     ListBox5.SelectedIndex = 0
   ' End If
    Me.PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(lastfoldr & (ListBox5.SelectedItem)) 
end if
```

Comment: FYI when you use the assignment operator `=` you **set** (replace) the value of the specified property/variable. Thus `ListBox5.SelectedIndex = +1` will always result in `1` because you are **setting** the value of `SelectedIndex` to positive 1. In order to _**increment**_ the value you must take the current value plus one, in other words: `ListBox5.SelectedIndex = ListBox5.SelectedIndex + 1` or the better, shorthand version: `ListBox5.SelectedIndex += 1`. **This applies to decrementing the value as well**.

Comment: It helps by thinking at everything on the right side of `=` as a mathematical operation. `+1` is just a positive number. The plus sign indicates that the value of `1` is positive. `x + 1` on the other hand is an operation. It takes the value of `x` and _adds_ `1`, which is totally different. It works exactly the same way in programming. `+1` alone will always just be a positive number (note that in programming `x += 1` is a shorthand of doing `x = x + 1`, so that is the only exception to this).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ListBox indexes go from 0 to ListBox.Items.Count -1 so whenever you ShowNextImage check if the index equals Count-1. if yes set index back to 0

```
Private Sub ShowNextImage()
    If LisBox5.SelectedIndex = ListBox5.Items.Count-1 then
        ListBox5.SelectedIndex = 0
    Else
        ListBox5.SelectedIndex +=1
    End If
```

Comment: @Visual Vincent @Mary
I try with 2 images loaded at listbox5... then i get Error at:




    `ListBox5.selectedIndex +=1`

Exception ot type "argumentOutOfRangeException"
InvalidArgument=The value '2' is not valid for 'SelectIndex' how can i solve that?

Comment: Edit your question to show your new code where this error occurs.

Comment: just noticed, I had a typo in ListBoxt.SelectedIndex = 0 Should be ListBox5.SelectedIndex = 0

Comment: @arc95 : Did you resolve your issue or do you still get that exception using Mary's code?